# I cant figure out this error in Heroku Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306. I can run localhost and heroku local web just not the heroku ap

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

[image]

Repo:

https://github.com/kfarshchian/my-menu

I have tried every possible solution I could find and nothing worked.

I tried adding a socket location in MySQL and didn't work. I have tried to add and remove .env stuff and that doesnt fix it.

Comment: It seems like you're expecting MySQL to be running on the dyno and exposed on localhost, which it absolutely won't be.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.